# Proper nesting of if statements

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I am writing some code for an 8x8 multiplier. I am using nested if statements. With the below code when the condition for a=x"02" is true then output `c` becomes undefined (`U`).

1) Is my nesting if statements correct?

2) Are there any syntax errors in my code during nesting?

```
entity mul is
Port ( 
       a : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
       b : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
       c : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0)
);
end mul;

architecture Behavioral of mul is
    signal s1,s2: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
begin
    process(b)
    begin
        s2 <= x"1B";
        if a = x"01" then
            c <= b;
-- ERROR OCCURING HERE
        elsif a = x"02" then
            if b(7) = '1' then
                s1(7) <= b(6);
                s1(6) <= b(5);
                s1(5) <= b(4);
                s1(4) <= b(3);
                s1(3) <= b(2);
                s1(2) <= b(1);
                s1(1) <= b(0);
                s1(0) <= '0';
                c <= s1 xor s2;
            else 
                s1(7) <= b(6);
                s1(6) <= b(5);
                s1(5) <= b(4);
                s1(4) <= b(3);
                s1(3) <= b(2);
                s1(2) <= b(1);
                s1(1) <= b(0);
                s1(0) <= '0';
                c <= s1;
            end if;
        elsif a = x"03" then
            if b(7) = '1' then
                s1(7) <= b(6);
                s1(6) <= b(5);
                s1(5) <= b(4);
                s1(4) <= b(3);
                s1(3) <= b(2);
                s1(2) <= b(1);
                s1(1) <= b(0);
                s1(0) <= '0';
                c <= (s1 xor s2) xor b;
            else 
                s1(7) <= b(6);
                s1(6) <= b(5);
                s1(5) <= b(4);
                s1(4) <= b(3);
                s1(3) <= b(2);
                s1(2) <= b(1);
                s1(1) <= b(0);
                s1(0) <= '0';
                c <= s1 xor b;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Two issues I can see straight away. (i) `a` should be in the _sensitivity list_ of your process. (ii) Signals do not update until a process finishes, so (eg) driving `s1` on one line and then reading on the next will not behave as you are expecting. Split these lines (and other similar ones) into separate processes (and make sure you get the sensitivity list right).

Comment: BTW:, you could just write `s1 <= b(6 downto 0) && '0';` making use of _slices_ and the _concatenation_ operator.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor thanks. It worked. I appreciate your help a lot.